# How to play AVI video in format SMB8, 0x38424D53?

Tags: macos, avi, video-playback

I have one video which can not be played on Mac OS X, and the output of MPlayer reads:

```
VIDEO:  [SMB8]  1280x1024  8bpp  200.000 fps  2097152.0 kbps (256000.0 kbyte/s)
Cannot find codec matching selected -vo and video format 0x38424D53.
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? It can be played in Windows with Windows Media Player, but I tried QuickTime, VLC, Mplayer on OS X and none of them can play this.

Comment: Where did you get the video from?